# Bootstrap navbar collapse keep open when click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to close the navbar click outside of it then I used this code

```
$(document).on('click',function(){              
        if(!$('#top_right_menu_btn').hasClass('open')) {
            $('#myNavbar').collapse('hide');
        }

    });
```

but it closes drop down menu even click on it, so I want to prevent from closing when clicking on it.

[my site](http://job.comeze.com/) (nav bar will appear when screen size below 768px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in the other answer but I have updated it below.

You need to run `.collapse()` on the navbar, not the toggle button.

```
$(".navbar-collapse").collapse('toggle');
```

Also you need to make sure that the click does not happen within the `.navbar` element.

```
!$(event.target).closest('.navbar').length
```

All together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in");
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.navbar').length && _opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('toggle');
        }
    });
});
```

[Example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4inYXwezUEIG0A7k7okI?p=preview)